# How to replace the second string by using the first string

Tags: string, bash, shell

i am trying to replace the second string by parameter 2.

the script takes the 2 parameters,then the script should check if the first parameter exist in file , if exist it should check in which line it is existing and it should replace only the second string in that file.

for ex: while running i am passing 2 parameters 1 and 2

```
./run.sh 1 2
```

the script should check if the parameter 1 exists if not it should write the parameter to file...now that is happening..

now if i pass the parameter 1 3 to script

the script should search where the parameter 1 is and replace 2nd string i.e 2 with 3..

How can i do this???

here is what i have tried

```
#!/bin/sh
#
FILE_PATH=/home/user/Desktop/script
FILE_NAME=$FILE_PATH/new.txt

echo $1
echo $2

param1=`cat $FILE_NAME | grep $1
if [ -z "$param1" ]
then
echo $1:$2 >> $FILE_NAME
else
param2=`cat $FILE_NAME | grep $1`
fi
```

the file which i am referring will have text like this

```
+abc.3434.res:192.168.2.34:5400
+efg.3123.co3:192.168.2.24:5440
+klm.gsdg.cm5:192.168.2.64:5403
```

if i pass parameter 1 as abc.3434.res and parameter 2 as 156.666.554.778
the script should replace

```
+abc.3434.res:192.168.2.34:5400 with
+abc.3434.res:156.666.554.778:5400
```

Comment: grep return 0 if match is found and 1 if not found. Use `-q` to supress any output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will look for all lines in the format you describe, and with the first parameter matching, and replace the middle bits with the second parameter.

```
sed -i -e "s/\(+$1:\).*\(:.*\)/\1$2\2/" $FILENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Awk:

```
awk -v f1="+$1" -v f2="$2" -F: '$1==f1 { $2=v2; s=1 }
    1
    END { if (!s) print f1 ":" f2 }' "$FILE_NAME"
```

Because Awk cannot access the shell's variables directly, we pass the values in with `-v`. The first condition matches when the first field is found; then the second field is changed, and `s` is set to 1 as a signal to ourselves that a substitution has taken place. The next line is unconditional, and simply prints all lines. At end of file, we add the new data if no match was found (`s` is zero).

Answer (score -1):

use the following format:

```
sed s/olsstring/newstring/g
```

such as :

```
cat /etc/passwd |sed s/root/jeff/g
```

But if you want to store to file immedaitly, you should use `-i`:

```
sed -i s/olsstring/newstring/g yourfile
```

**But grep and another command:**

shell has a variable `$?` , it print `return status`
if you want to invoke for grep command, you should use :

```
grep -i blahblah |egrep -v egrep 
if [$0 == 0 ];then 
 echo SUCCESS
fi;
```